Server time out issue after 3 mins
If my api call taking more than 3 mins, i'm getting server time out issue in abp boilerplate framework application. this issue is happens in hosted environment not local environment. where i should increase it's time out?
My api will take time depends on the records they use in the request. like it may take 3 or 10 or 20 so what will be the proper way to overcome this problem?

Making changes in web.config executionTimeout="300".
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
context.RequestAborted = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)).Token;
await next.Invoke();
});

which one will help me?

"where i should increase it's time out?" - you shouldn't. Switch to a suitable pattern for a long-running operations.

If I understood your question correctly, you need set keepalive setting on kestrel server if you are using it (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/options?view=aspnetcore-8.0).
But setting timeout there only doesn't solves the problem, In hosted environments there are reverse proxies(nginx,IIs etc), gateways etc involved between the services that are communicating. so you have to control timeouts at every level to sync.
The client making the request should sync with these timeouts configured.
In the end the solution for your problem is not timeout but a different approach to handle this. May be Async Apis, webhooks might help your case.
https://medium.com/@satyendra.jaiswal/webhooks-and-asynchronous-apis-real-time-communication-patterns-b6dee06b855d
